# Prime ideals in a finite direct product of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $S=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{R_i}$ where each $R_i$ is a commutative ring with identity. The prime ideals of $S$ are of the form $\prod_{i=1}^{n}{P_i}$ where for some $j$, $P_j$ is a prime ideal of $R_j$ and for $i\neq j$, $P_i=R_i$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is clear that any ideal of $S$ of the form stated above is prime. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $S$. For $1\leq k\leq n$, let $e_k$ be the element of $S$ whose $k$th coordinate is $1$ and all other coordinates are $0$. $P$ is proper, so some $e_j$ (say $e_1$) is not in $P$. For $k\neq 1$ we have $e_{1}e_k=0\in P$, so $e_k\in P$. Thus $0\times \prod_{i=2}^{n}{R_i}\subseteq P$. Let $\pi_1\colon S\to R_1$ be the canonical projection. Then $\pi_1(P)$ is a prime ideal of $R_1$ and $P=\pi_1(P)\times \prod_{i=2}^{n}{R_i}.$

Comment: Can you clarify why $\pi_1 (P)$ is prime in $R_1$?

Comment: @Prospect Because of the following: 
Suppose $xy \in \pi_1(P)$ for some $x,y \in R_1$. 

Thus there is $(xy,t_1,t_2,...) \in P$. $P$ is prime, thus $(x,t_1,t_2,...) \in P$ or $(y,1,1,...) \in P$. Hence $x \in \pi_1(P)$ or $y \in \pi_1(P)$.

Comment: So, what is the ring R in this answer? S itself?

Answer (score 11):

Let $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ be two commutative rings with unity.

Let $P$ be a prime ideal in $S=R_{1} \times R_{2}$.

Let $ P= P_{1} \times P_{2}$ where $P_{1}$ is a ideal in $R_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ is a ideal in $R_{2}$.

Then $S/P \simeq R_{1}/P_{1}  \times R_{2}/P_{2} $.

In the whole quotient ring we have $(\hat 1,0)(0,\hat 1)=(0,0)$, hence one of $\hat 1$ it must be zero in the summand quotient ring which means $R_1/P_1 =0$ or $R_2/P_2 =0$. And the whole quotient ring which is integral domain will isomorphism to the non zero summand ring, which will turn to be a integral ring, hence its factor will be a prime ideal.

Therefore only one of the  $P_{1}$ or $P_{2}$ is a prime ideal and other should be corresponding ring.

Comment: The other ideal should be the corresponding ring. Thanks for pointing that out, I think the proof is complete now.

Comment: Why you know they are isomorphic ? I don't understand what implies  that the product of two integral domains is not an integral domain.

Comment: @VeganMaths in the product of two integral domains there are two non zero elements namely (1,0) and (0,1), whose product is (0,0). This is what makes product of two or more integral domains not an integral domain.